# Ошибка подключения к БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Не подключается к СУБД MySQL. "Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: 0".
Все пароли и логины совпадают, на компе тоже всё подключено правильно, это не первый проект на устройстве.

Через консоль есть подключение к СУБД.

Даю пинг на имя сайта, ip находит

```
`<?php

$dblocation = "localhost";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbtable = "requests";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];



if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

try {
        // Подключение к базе данных
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dblocation;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        // Устанавливаем корректную кодировку
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        // Собираем данные для запроса
        $data = array( 'name' => $name, 'message' => $message, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone );
        // Подготавливаем SQL-запрос
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $dbtable (name, message, email, phone ) values (:name, :message, :email, :phone)");
        // Выполняем запрос с данными
        $query->execute($data);
        // Запишим в переменую, что запрос отрабтал
        $result = true;
        $link = true;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Если есть ошибка соединения или выполнения запроса, выводим её
        print "Ошибка!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}

if ($result) {
    echo "Успех. Информация занесена в базу данных";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: думаете перед каждым запросом надо заново коннектится к БД ?

Comment: А при чем здесь `mysqli_connect_errno` если вы используете PDO?

Comment: и что, прям так на русском ошибка вылазит?

Comment: $result нельзя присваивать true, потому что запрос к бд может не выполниться.

Answer (score 0):

Переменные dbuser, dbname, dbpass остаются пустыми (хотя dbpass  может быть пустым). Мне кажется причина в этом.